# Tween.registerAccessor NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, libgdx, tween

i 'm a newbie for LibGDX and Android. Btw sorry for my bad English.

Here is my problem. I just want to make a splash screen with libgdx and i watched Dustin Riley 's libGDX tutorial on youtube. But my codes doesn 't work and here is LogCat about error.

```
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.me.secondGame.tween.SpriteTween
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.me.secondGame.screens.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:57)
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.me.secondGame.secondGame.create(secondGame.java:10)
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:292)
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.GLSurfaceViewCupcake$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceViewCupcake.java:708)
05-07 11:05:19.004: E/AndroidRuntime(838):  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.GLSurfaceViewCupcake$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceViewCupcake.java:646)
```

Firstly i wrote codes and that 's work without any problem. But i added some tween codes and now it doesn 't work.

Here is added code

```
Tween.registerAccessor(Sprite.class, new SpriteTween()); //MY ERROR ON HERE

manager = new TweenManager();

Tween.to(splashSprite, SpriteTween.ALPHA, 2f).target(1).ease(TweenEquations.easeInQuad).start(manager);
```

I guess there is a logical mistake. Because there is no error output.

And my SpriteTween codes.

```
package com.me.secondGame.tween;

import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import aurelienribon.tweenengine.TweenAccessor;

public class SpriteTween implements TweenAccessor<Sprite> {
    public static final int ALPHA = 1;

    @Override
    public int getValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] returnValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            returnValues[0] = target.getColor().a;
            return 1;
        default:
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValues(Sprite target, int tweenType, float[] newValues) {
        switch (tweenType) {
        case ALPHA:
            target.setColor(1, 1, 1, newValues[0]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I can 't get what is problem and now my head 's gonna blow up.

Edited:

After Guian 's posts i created new project with guides said. Btw i watched tutorial again.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: did you follow the steps in 'android project setup' from the libGDX's google code page ?  link : https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup

Comment: Or probably, there is another case that is similar to my project. Here's the interesting part on why there is 'NoClassDefFoundError' on tween engine for Android LibGDX based games: when you run it on desktop starter, the tween engine works; however, when you run it on Android starter, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This  kind of error happens if a class is found during compile time but not found at runtime.

You need to check that the Tween `.jar` file is properly included in your classpath and packaged into your APK.

Double check the inclusion process seen at [Android Project Setup](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup) in the libGDX's google code page.

For example, the "**libs**" folder has to be called 'libs', not 'lib' nor anything else  to be properly included in the APK.  The Tween engine `.jar` file must be in this directory.  Having the `.jar` file just in the Eclipse "Java Build Path" is insufficient.

More on this topic can be read at : [NoClassDefFoundError in Java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html)

Comment: Thanks your advice. Now i 'm at school and when i 'll be at house i will try that solution.

Comment: Man, you saved my day. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

I did this and all gone well:

Drag the tween engine jar from folder to the project, right click in it, "add library", select android