# NoClassDefFoundError while launching libGDX on android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

My libGDX project uses the Tween API for animations on my splash screen. On running the android launcher, the application force closes with the following error:

```
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ekshiksha.vcl.screens.SpriteTween
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at com.ekshiksha.vcl.screens.SplashScreen.show(SplashScreen.java:55)
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at com.ekshiksha.vcl.MyVclLab.create(MyVclLab.java:16)
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:292)
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.GLSurfaceViewCupcake$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceViewCupcake.java:708)
06-04 11:07:02.257: E/AndroidRuntime(3905):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.GLSurfaceViewCupcake$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceViewCupcake.java:646)
```

Is it because I did not add the tween engine `.jar` file to my build path in android project? And should I link the `jar` file or make a new `libs` folder in android project and copy it there?

Comment: You can use this: http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2012/04/new-app-libgdx-project-setup/ to create your project. It will add everything for you.

Comment: yes i had done it exactly this way. without any third party libraries it runs fine.

Comment: if you have updated adt to rev 22. right click on your project goto properties. java build path. Choose order export tab. make sure android private libraries is checked . clean an build.

Comment: yes that is checked too. but I found the solution right now in another SO post. will post it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, the solution in the following post solved my problem of launching the android application.

[Tween.registerAccessor NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16417401/tween-registeraccessor-noclassdeffounderror)

All I needed to do is link the tween API library in the android project and check it in order and export.